# Which Maven source directory should contain application.xml? - src/main/config or src/main/resources

Tags: maven

Which Maven source directory should contain `application.xml`? - `src/main/config` or `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be in the `resources` directory. Maven will copy everything is that directory to the `target/classes` directory which is probably what you want.